# How to enable grunt reload after less compilation?

Tags: less, gruntjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created a grunt project, installed bootstrap and grunt-contrib-less and configured grunt to

- Listen for less file changes and run the 'less' task appropiately (Working)
- Compile Bootstrap.less on the 'less' task (Working)
- Reload the browser upon less compilation (Not working)

[Here is my gruntfile](http://pastie.org/8430154). Anything wrong with it?

Also bonus points for whoever tells me why dropping in grunt-recess to replace grunt-contrib-less (As in replacing 'less' with 'recess' on the tasks) works but aborts with a lot of compilation errors.
More bonus points to whoever tells me why less compilation is working when Twitter only supports compiling bootstrap with recess.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The gruntfile seems ok. Assuming that the "watch" task is working, the livereload of the browser can happen only with a plugin installed. See http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/86242-how-do-i-install-and-use-the-browser-extensions- for [Safari](http://download.livereload.com/2.0.9/LiveReload-2.0.9.safariextz), [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei) or [Firefox](http://download.livereload.com/2.0.8/LiveReload-2.0.8.xpi) extensions.

For your compilation errors, notice that `Grunt-contrib-less` is using [less v1.5](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less/blob/master/package.json) when `recess` still use [less v1.3](https://github.com/twitter/recess/blob/master/package.json).
See [this issue on github](https://github.com/twitter/recess/issues/107).

This mean, for example, that compiling with `recess` you can't [use the SourceMap feature](http://roots.io/using-less-source-maps/).